# OCaml cant get array length

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to make shifting of array.
But I'm getting syntax error on `arr.length`. (2nd line)

```
let shift (arr : array) (k : int) =
    let size = arr.length;;
    let shifted = Array.make size 0;;

    for i = 0 to size- 1 do
        if i < k
        then shifted.(size- 1 - k + i) <- arr.(i);;
        else shifted.(i-k) <- arr.(i);;
    done

    shifted;;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code.

First, the `;;` symbol really isn't part of OCaml syntax. It's used only in the interpreter (the toplevel or REPL) to tell the interpreter when to evaluate what you've typed so far. In ordinary source code it's only rarely used. Many people (including me) adopt a style where `;;` is *never* used in source files.

By contrast, you are ending just about every line with `;;`, which is guaranteed to cause syntax errors.

The way to define local variables of a function looks like this:

```
let var = expr in
(* rest of function comes here *)
```

So you should have

```
let size = Array.length arr in
let shifted = Array.make size 0 in
. . .
```

You should remove all your `;;` tokens and add `in` as necessary.

In addition, you are using a kind of object-oriented syntax. But Arrays are not OO-style objects. To get the length of an array named arr:

```
Array.length arr
```

Here's how it looks:

```
# let arr = Array.make 10 0;;
val arr : int array = [|0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0|]
# Array.length arr;;
- : int = 10
# Array.length [| "another"; "example" |];;
- : int = 2
```

In other words, `length` is a function defined in the `Array` module. An OCaml array isn't an object (of the OO sort) and doesn't have methods.

(For future reference, methods of OCaml objects are referenced using `#`, as in `object#method`.)

Answer (score 0):

As an added suggestion, we can use [`Array.init`](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Array.html#VALinit) and exception handling to implement this quite readily by having the `Invalid_argument` exception thrown by an out of bounds access handled by returning `0`.

```
# let shift arr k =
    Array.init 
      (Array.length arr)
      (fun i -> try arr.(i + k) with Invalid_argument _ -> 0)
val shift : int array -> int -> int array = <fun>
# shift [|1; 2; 3; 4|] 1;;
- : int array = [|2; 3; 4; 0|]
# shift [|1; 2; 3; 4|] 2;;
- : int array = [|3; 4; 0; 0|]
```

A further refinement might provide a default value so that the type of `shift` can be generalized to `'a array -> int -> 'a -> 'a array`.